# How to promote oxidation of copper(I) chloride to copper(II) chloride with oxygen in solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, transition-metals, catalysis

I recently discovered that copper(I) chloride in hydrochloric acid can react at about 80 °C with bubbled-in oxygen gas and oxidize into copper(II) chloride. I found almost no documentation on the web, but this is my suggested reaction:

$$\ce{4 CuCl + 4 HCl + O2 -> 2 H2O + 4 CuCl2}$$

However, the reaction is incredibly slow, taking at least several hours per mole. Does anyone know of any catalyst that may speed it up by a considerable amount? (by that I mean any amount). If not, is there a way to see what type of catalyst may work on this reaction?

Comment: This reaction is immediate if you replace $\ce{O2}$ by $\ce{H2O2}$

Comment: That is not an option, it has to be done with air or pure oxygen

Comment: Every useful relevant word omitted in the question formulation is paid later by several words posted by responders and the question poster during clarification. Provide sufficient relevant context/background in your question, otherwise receiving not applicable advices is your fault.